# What did QWidget* QApplication::mainWidget() become in Qt4?

Tags: c++, qt4

I am porting an application from Qt3 to Qt4, and need a Qt4 replacement for QApplication::mainWidget() which used to return the top-level widget in Qt3. Does anyone know how to do this in Qt4?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Technically, any widget initialized with NULL is a top level widget so QApplication shouldn't assume that one of them is better than another.
The way I usually do it is to save a pointer to the "real" main widget somewhere, even a global variable or a singleton and reference it when needed.

Answer (score 2):

I think [topLevelWidgets()](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.5/qapplication.html#topLevelWidgets) is as close at it can be.

Edit:

Yup. Qt4 added complexity (and power). There is no application wide MainWidget anymore. Many QMainWindows can be created and shown, and hidden, and shown again. This is a good thing, though :)
As shoosh noticed, QT3 behaviour can be easily simulated with global variable (yuck!) or QApplication subclass.

Comment: Yeah, I saw this method. But it felt like a step in the wrong direction since it adds complexity. This is so far the only case where I feel that the Qt3 was better than Qt4, and that's why I had to ask. I will leave the question open a little bit longer, but if no one comes up with anything better I will accept your answer. Thanks..

Comment: Well, you always can keep track of "main widget" yourself, depending on your app.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're looking for has been replaced by the [QMainWindow](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.5/qmainwindow.html) class, which does allow you to set a [set](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.5/qmainwindow.html#setCentralWidget) and [get](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.5/qmainwindow.html#centralWidget) a central widget.